# Why is the const variable defined like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants

I'm finding it hard to understand how the following code snippet (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-get-started#Query)) works.

```
const { result: results } = await client.database(databaseId).container(containerId).items.query(querySpec, {enableCrossPartitionQuery:true}).toArray();
for (var queryResult of results) {
     let resultString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
     console.log(`\tQuery returned ${resultString}\n`);
}
```

Why is the iteration done on `results` rather than `result` because as I understand we are creating an object with a property named `result` and there is no variable elsewhere declared with the name `results`?

Comment: `{ result: results }` puts the `result` property into a variable named `results`

Comment: It's called destructuring assignment. It gets the `results` property from the right hand object, instantiates a new const named `result` and assigns that value there.

Check here more 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: `const { result: results } = someObject;` is equivalent to `const results = someObject.result;`

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks for the simple explanation! I get it now. I thought it was always `{property:value}`. This was new to me!